# How do I use MYSQL as the database in a Django project?

Tags: python, mysql, django

The default database of the Django is sqlite, however I want to use MYSQL instead.
Since the `MYSQLdb` module is not supported in python3.x, the official doc of django recommend using `mysqlclient` and `MySQL Connector/Python`instead.Here is the original doc:

> MySQL has a couple drivers that implement the Python Database API described in PEP 249:
>   • mysqlclient is a native driver. It’s the recommended choice.
>   • MySQL Connector/Python is a pure Python driver from Oracle that does not require the MySQL client library
>   or any Python modules outside the standard library.
>   These drivers are thread-safe and provide connection pooling.
>   In addition to a DB API driver, Django needs an adapter to access the database drivers from its ORM. Django provides
>   an adapter for mysqlclient while MySQL Connector/Python includes its own.

I've got the latest version of `mysql-client` and `mysql-connector-python`, but as I execute the`migrate`command, error occurs.Here is part of the message:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x7f2112e99d90>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/lothakim/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in 
>       import MySQLdb as Database
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'MySQLdb'django.
> .........
> core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
> Did you install mysqlclient?

It seems to be the problem of the database connection.But I followed every step of the official tutorial.How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you installed MySQLdb? pip install mysqlclient

Comment: You need to show your DATABASES setting.

Comment: Note that `mysql-client` and `mysqlclient` are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

It's a silly mistake...
I confuse the `mysql-client` with `mysqlclient`.The former is part of the MYSQL application, while the latter is a python module.I didn't install the latter.
Also note you should `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`before `pip install mysqlclient`.

Comment: Don't feel silly, the naming of packages in the DB space is pretty confusing. :)